# unecessary blank first line in output

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool isletter(char c)
{
    return ((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z'));
}
bool capital(char c)
{
    return (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z');
}

bool small(char c)
{
    return (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z');
}

int main()
{
    char a[26];
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        a[i] = getchar();
        char c = a[i];

        if (isletter(c) == false) {
            cout << "error" << endl;
            return (0);
        }
    }
    //----------------reading of text------------------
    char text[10000], character;
    int i = 0;
    do {
        character = getchar();
        text[i] = character;
        i++;
    } while (character != EOF);
    //-----------------crypt----------------------
    for (int j = 0; j < i - 1; j++) {
        if (small(text[j]))
            text[j] = a[text[j] - 'a'];
        else if (capital(text[j]))
            text[j] = a[text[j] - 'A'] - 32;
        cout << text[j];
    }
}
```

this is a program used for cryptography. it works pk except that it prints at the beginning an empty line.

example

```
input;
 1:   cbjalmvopqruytiezksnxdfghw
    2:   Once upon a time in China, some believe, around the year one double-ought three,
    3:   head priest of the White Lotus Clan, Pai Mei was walking down the road,
    4:   contemplating whatever it is that a man of Pai Mei's infinite power contemplates
    5:   - which is another way of saying "who knows" - when a Shaolin monk appeared,
    6:   traveling in the opposite direction.  As the monk and the priest crossed paths,
    7:   Pai Mei, in a practically unfathomable display of generosity, gave the monk the
    8:   slightest of nods.  The nod was not returned.
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
 1: Itjl xeit c npyl pt Joptc, siyl blupldl, ckixta nol hlck itl aixbul-ixvon nokll,
    2:olca␣ekplsn␣im␣nol␣Fopnl␣Uinxs␣Juct,␣Ecp␣Ylp␣fcs␣fcurptv␣aift␣nol␣kica,↲
    3:jitnlyeucnptv␣focnldlk␣pn␣ps␣nocn␣c␣yct␣im␣Ecp␣Ylp's␣ptmptpnl␣eiflk␣jitnlyeucnls↲
    4:-␣fopjo␣ps␣ctinolk␣fch␣im␣schptv␣"foi␣rtifs"␣-␣folt␣c␣Sociupt␣yitr␣ceelckla,↲
    5:nkcdluptv␣pt␣nol␣ieeispnl␣apkljnpit.␣␣Cs␣nol␣yitr␣cta␣nol␣ekplsn␣jkissla␣ecnos,↲
    6:Ecp␣Ylp,␣pt␣c␣ekcjnpjcuuh␣xtmcnoiycbul␣apseuch␣im␣vltlkispnh,␣vcdl␣nol␣yitr␣nol↲
    7:supvonlsn␣im␣tias.␣␣Nol␣tia␣fcs␣tin␣klnxktla.↲
```

OUTPUT

```
1: 
2: Itjl xeit c npyl pt Joptc, siyl blupldl, ckixta nol hlck itl aixbul-ixvon nokll,
    3:olca␣ekplsn␣im␣nol␣Fopnl␣Uinxs␣Juct,␣Ecp␣Ylp␣fcs␣fcurptv␣aift␣nol␣kica,↲
    4:jitnlyeucnptv␣focnldlk␣pn␣ps␣nocn␣c␣yct␣im␣Ecp␣Ylp's␣ptmptpnl␣eiflk␣jitnlyeucnls↲
    5:-␣fopjo␣ps␣ctinolk␣fch␣im␣schptv␣"foi␣rtifs"␣-␣folt␣c␣Sociupt␣yitr␣ceelckla,↲
    6:nkcdluptv␣pt␣nol␣ieeispnl␣apkljnpit.␣␣Cs␣nol␣yitr␣cta␣nol␣ekplsn␣jkissla␣ecnos,↲
    7:Ecp␣Ylp,␣pt␣c␣ekcjnpjcuuh␣xtmcnoiycbul␣apseuch␣im␣vltlkispnh,␣vcdl␣nol␣yitr␣nol↲
    8:supvonlsn␣im␣tias.␣␣Nol␣tia␣fcs␣tin␣klnxktla.↲
```

Comment: Could you make your code more readable by applying some of code indent styles? You can use this online service https://clang-format-configurator.site/ and choose any favorite style base.

Comment: you leave a newline in the input after reading the key so that becomes the first character of `text`

Answer (score 0):

> you leave a newline in the input after reading the key so that becomes the first character of text

–
Alan Birtles

Comment: thanks for your answer. How can i fix this?

Comment: cin.ignore( numeric_limits<streamsize>::max() '\n');
i tried using this but it didnt work

Comment: @user23076731 why are you using `getchar()` at all? You are mixing C and C++ I/O.  Use `cin.get()`, `cin.getline()` or `std::getline()` instead to read in the whole input at one time.  The `getline()` versions can eat the newline for you so you don't have to `ignore()` it manually.